# Write stdout into a string variable

Tags: c++, string, stdout

I have written a program in C++ in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) platform which print my required output into the stdout in every second. It means, after 10 seconds, I have 100 lines (each stdout in every second is 2 lines report) in the stdout.

This is my applied simulation format and i cannot change any variable or method to write the output into the variable instead of the stdout.

I am going to save this output into the string variable instead of the stdout. How is it possible by C++ language?

Comment: When you say "stdout" do you mean you tse `printf()` or `fprintf(stdout, ...)`? In that case I don't think there is a solution. If you mean `std::cout` there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string stream for that. Suppose your original logging function is like this:

```
void log(std::ostream & o, std::string msg)
{
    o << msg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    log(std::cout, "Ping");
}
```

Change this to:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    // ...
    log(oss, "Ping");
}
```

If that's not an option, you can mangle the global `std::cout`'s output buffer:

```
std::streambuf * sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();   // save original

std::ostringstream oss;
std::cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());                // redirect to "oss"

// ...

std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);                       // restore original
```

In either case, `oss.str()` contains the string data.

Comment: How can i band the stdout printing by the default program and allow to print my own string variable (oss.str()) with my format in the stdout?

Comment: @BlueBit: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you want to format?

Comment: I mean, i do not want to my default stdout in my program be printed. Just copy the stdout into the string variable. How can i band the printing stdout? Is it clear, friend? :-)

Comment: @BlueBit: The last part with changing `rdbuf` should accomplish that. Give it a try, and see also the answer I linked in the "duplicate" comment above.

Comment: What does "Ping" mean? I should replace "Ping" with std::cout? because you mention: log(oss, "Ping"); It just send "Ping" to stdout. Yes?